# Generating a Unique ID based on values in related columns

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet at work that has been tracking orders, however there is no unique Order ID that has been kept with these orders. I am wanting to create unique Order IDs in column M based on the data in columns A, B & K.

For example, rows 2,3,4 & 5 could have an order IDs of 1,2,3,4 respectively. However rows 6 & 7 should have an order ID of 5, as those rows have the same duplicate order data (same date, store & customer).

How would I go about creating unique ID numbers, especially in the case of duplicate rows?

Apologies - I am a new user to Stackoverflow, so I can't embed my sample image directly into this post - a link is generated instead below

Example spreadsheet data

[image]

Comment: You can just concatenate your columns which will create a unique id `CONCAT(A2:B2,K2)` although this isn't going to be pretty (i.e. it's a long string), it's still unique. If you just need this key for the sake of unique counts then this is sufficient. If you want a actual order number, you will need to do some more work using the concatenation as the foundation

Comment: I would concatenate the Date,store number and the customer number and return that as text.  Date is stored as a double and concatenating it will return the double value and not something that looks like a date.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is a great start. I can most likely trim down the output from that formula into something more usable. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can create a short & long key using something like so:**

1. First create a unique value given the info you have with `CONCAT(A2:C2)`
2. Index into the range to find the current max key and increment for new values with `=IFERROR(INDEX(E$1:E1,MATCH(D2,D$1:D2,0)),MAX(E$1:E1)+1)`

*Equations are based on sample data built below. Add formulas to second row and drag down as needed*

[image]

You can modify the keys further to create a standard format. Maybe something like:

1. Store # - Order Number (*EX: 00633 - 0001*)
2. Customer # - Order Number (*EX: 423480 - 0003*)
3. 5 Digit ID Key (*EX: `=TEXT(ID Key, "00000") = 00001`*)

---

**You can also just make your unique key the combination of `Date` - `Store #` - `Customer #` with:**

```
=TEXT(A2, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " - " & LEFT(B2,SEARCH(" -",B2)) & " - " & LEFT(C2,SEARCH(" -",C2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot mate - this one has done the trick. Your formula in step 2 at the start of your answer did wonders. Cheers!